# SONAR too long function for anonymous self-executing function

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have a self-(or rather jQuery-)executing anonymous function that executes some code scoped in smaller functions inside. Like:

```
jQuery(function() {
    function A(){}
    function B(){}
    ...
    do-sth-with-A-B-and-others      
 });
```

I thought it's a valid pattern to avoid cluttering global namespace, while having the code more-or-less elegantly organized. Now, SONAR says:

> Line 1:
>   [true] New: Javascript:S138 Severity: MAJOR, Message: This function has 280 lines, which is greater than the 100 lines authorized. Split it into smaller functions.

Is the point SONAR is making here valid?

Comment: If you set up SONAR with this rule, you'd better follow it every time than just some... You set up the rules SONAR uses, so I'd say you are the best one placed to say if it is valid or not.